# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift

I have a photo view app which which I use `Alamofire` to get the data and use `RxSwift` to observer changes in the `API`. everything works well and I can print the total number of returned items and even print individual items but the app crashes when ever I set my `UIlabel` text to the title value got from the code. I do not know why this is any help would be appreciated.

the crash is `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

**Main cell**

```
func configueCell(flickerPhotoModel: FlickrPhotoModel) -> Void {

        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        print("Cell \(String(describing: flickerPhotoModel.id))")
        flikrTitle.text = flickerPhotoModel.title
    }
```

**PhotoViewModel**

```
private func setupPageBinding() {
        currentState.asObservable()

            .subscribe(onNext: { currentState in
            if currentState == .initialLoading || currentState == .loadingNextPage {
                self.fetchNextPageOfPhotos()
            }
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        photos.asObservable()
            .map { $0.count > 0 ? self.currentPage.value + 1 : self.currentPage.value }
            .bind(to: currentPage)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

**COntroller**

```
private func setupCollectionViewBinding() {
        print("JSONNN x \(self.viewModel.photos.value.count)")
        viewModel.photos
            .asObservable()
            .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, cellType: MainCell.self))
            { _, photo, cell in
                cell.configueCell(flickerPhotoModel: photo)
                print("JSONNN 5 \(self.viewModel.photos.value.count)")
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        viewModel.currentState
            .asObservable()
            .map { $0 == .initialLoading || $0 == .initialLoadingFailure }
            .bind(to: collectionView.rx.isHidden)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        collectionView.rx.modelSelected(FlickrPhotoModel.self)
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                self.routingDelegate?.handlePhotoSelection($0)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Comment: is the cell registered with the collection view?

Comment: I do not understand your question @PeterPajchl

Comment: I registered it in the viewController like this `collectionView.register(MainCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

Comment: Check your flikrTitle label and flickerPhotoModel.title, One of them should be nil.

Comment: yes, that's what I was after; based on how you create your cell (storyboard, nib) is to check if you have linked the reference/IBOutlet to the `flikrTitle` UILabel

Comment: everything is well linked.

Comment: Are you getting your `flickerPhotoModel.title` correctly from server?

Comment: print("Cell label:\\(flikrTitle)  flickerPhotoModel.title:\\(String(describing: flickerPhotoModel.title))") and check which one is nil. If both has value, then your issue is in different place.

Comment: printing this `print("JSONNN label\(String(describing: cell.flikrTitle.text)))")` crashes the app

Comment: I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check for UILabel, it may not be having connection in Interface Builder/StoryBoard.